# Webhooks not triggering in JIRA OnDemand if the url is HTTPS

Tags: jira, jira-ondemand

My JIRA server is hosted in Cloud.

- Why Webhooks not triggering the external URL if that is HTTPS?
- Is there any settings/Configuration in JIRA to call an HTTPS URL in
  web hooks?

Comment: Are you listening for a POST on the given URL?

Comment: Yes.. If I give HTTP instead HTTPS, everything working without any issue. But I want to POST using HTTPS from JIRA webhooks.

Comment: What certificate is signing the exchange? Is it self signed?

Comment: Yes Bartlomiej, its self signed certificate.

Comment: you may want to try this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9382122/jira-webhooks-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: It seems this solution is for Standalone JIRA server. In my case am using JIRA OnDemand Server which is hosted in Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is explained in the following link

[Link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/31659016/webhooks-not-triggering-in-jira-ondemand-if-the-url-is-https)